# Number NOT followed by variable (a letter) in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I did not find an answer to my problem so I hope that we can solve it here! Let's say I have this string:

```
String string = "1 + 1555.0056q + 34.0g - 451-0.7855";
```

I want to define a regex that can find all the constants and NOT the coefficients. So I would like to find just 1,- 451 and -0.7855. So far I can find coefficients, but only if they are not at the end of the string, because my regex depends on them not having a letter after them and then a whitespace or "-" or "+". This is how it looks:

```
\\s*(\\-|\\+)\\s*\\d+\\.?\\d+[a-zA-Z]{0}(\\s|\\+|\\-)
```

I also tried:

```
\\s*(\\-|\\+)\\s*\\d+\\.?\\d+(!?[a-zA-Z])
```

which did not work at all! So, could you help me extract only the constants, even if they are at the end of the string? Explaining what the new parts that you add does would be very helpful :)

Comment: May I suggest that it may be easier to first match all the constants or coefficients with their variables, and then to eliminate the ones containing variables in a later step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use positive lookahead assertion.

```
[+-]?\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[-+\s]|$)
```

`[+-]?` would match an optional `+` or `-` symbol. `\s*` matches zero or more spaces. `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` would match integer as well as floating point numbers. `(?=[-+\s]|$)` positive lookahead asserts that the match must be followed by a space or `-` or `+` or `$` end of the line anchor.

Java regex would be,

```
"[+-]?\\s*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?=[-+\\s]|$)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iJ9fB2/1)

Code:

```
String str = "1 + 1555.0056q + 34.0g - 451-0.7855";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[+-]?\\s*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?=[-+\\s]|$)").matcher(str);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
1
- 451
-0.7855
```

Comment: for a second I was confused at `(?:\.\d+)`, then I realised you had `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` which would only match valid numbers with a single decimal point followed only by numbers. Smart thinking. +1

Comment: Thank you! So if I understand it correctly, instead of checking that there is no letter after if, you check so that there is in fact either a **space**, a **+** a **-** or **end of line**?

Furthermore, I don't understand what the **?:** does in `(?:\\.\\d+)`

Comment: `(?:...)` called non-capturing group. Which won't capture any characters.

Answer (score -2):

This works: `(-\s?)?[\d.]+(?![.\w])`

Comment: @nhahtdh pfff ... Read the question. It is not about validating arbitrary strings, but rather about extracting numeric constants from a formula. This can be trivially updated (`\d+(\.\d+)?` instead of `[\d.]+`)to require matches start with a digit and contain at most a single period, but in my opinion, it would be wrong to unnecessarily overcomplicate the expression to make it satisfy a non-existent requirement ... and even then, it would still allow input like "this is not (123) a valid formula at all!", which is, probably, not the intention either.

Comment: @nhahtdh the cost of readability and maintainability of your code is *never* "low". What is your "defensive programming" defending against anyway? You would not reject an invalid formula by using a more complicated and less comprehensible regex, you would just *silently* skip and ignore *some* of the  garbage in it. In which universe is it "defensive"?

Comment: @nhahtdh and also, whatever your stance on "defensive programming" may be, it  does not justify downvoting of this answer, as it is both a *correct* and *useful* answer to the original question. If you disagree with me on the meaning of the term "defensive programming", write a blog about it, but voting on unrelated answers is hardly a forum to further your agenda.

Comment: Removed my comment about the defensive programming, since your point stands in this case. You are right that adding more doesn't really help defending the program against bad input, which the question doesn't mention anything about. But I stand by my downvote, since a one-liner answer doesn't really help people learn anything.

Comment: @nhahdth you are still wrong. There are plenty of comprehensive regex guides online (like [this one] (http://www.regular-expressions.info)) that can "help people learn". The purpose of the *answer* is to *answer the question*. Some questions are more general than others, and  give you a possibility to actually learn something from the answers. Others, like "how do I match numbers, not followed by a letter" aren't like that. That does not make direct  answers to them less useful to those who are looking to answer the question.

Comment: I think we agree to disagree on how an answer should look like. After using SO for more than 2 years, my later answers tend to include at least some sort of assumptions (which regex answers usually make but never stated), maybe some explanation why OP's regex doesn't work, and something OP may not know.

Comment: @nhahtdh well, *that* would (usually) justify a downvote. You are trying to substitute the real requirements for your own again, like with your `....` theory. The OP "may not know" lots of stuff, but what he expects from you is to *answer his question*, not act as a mentor in his life journey. If the question was why his regex did not work, the useful answers would need to include an explanation. But as it is, he obviously does not care why his attempt is not working, he either already knows it, or does not need to know. What he needs is a solution to his problem, not a life couching session.